# jQuery issue - How to perform two actions with only one button

Tags: jquery

I currently have two buttons. The first button shows a div. The second button shows the second div.

Here is a link to the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWYZZg)

...and here is my current jQuery...

```
$(function(){
  $('#first').click(function () {
      $('.val').delay(500).slideDown(); 
  });

 $('#second').click(function () {
$('.val2').prependTo('.applied').delay(500).slideDown(400, function(){
        $('.total').html('£104.00');
      });
  });
});
```

What I would like to do is to show both divs with only one button. So the user would select the button to show the first div. Then when they press the same button again it will show the second div. I am thinking I may need to use an 'if statement' to say if the current is showing, then show the second, but my code doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set something to "slide down" if changes its visibility property :)

```
if ($('.second').is(':visible'))
{
     //show first
}
else
{
   //show second
}
```

After second click both gonna be visible :) In your situation:

```
$('#first').click(function () {

    if($('.val2').is(':visible'))
         $('.val').delay(500).slideDown(); 
    else    
        $('.val2').prependTo('.applied').delay(500).slideDown(400, 
           function(){
                $('.total').html('£104.00');
           });   

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking the visibility of elements using jQuery can be tricky. You can however use the value attribute to store state.

```
<button id="button" value="none">Click Me</button>
```

and the script:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var state = $this.val();

    if (state = 'none'){
        //do first action
        $this.val('first');
    else if (state = 'first'){
        //do second action
        $this.val('second');
    else{
        //reset maybe?
        $this.val('none');
    }
});
```

Or you could use a switch statement or similar to manage more states

Answer (score 1):

> Without if statement

```js
$('#first').one("click",function () {
    $('.val').delay(500).slideDown(); 
    bind()
 });


var bind=function(){
  $('#first').one("click",function () {
  $('.val2')
      .prependTo('.applied')
      .delay(500)
      .slideDown(400,function(){
         $('.total').html('£104.00');
      });
  });
  
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #5c5c5c;
}

.main {
 max-width: 375px;
  margin:16px;
}
button {
  padding:16px;
  border-radius:2px;
  border:0;
  background:seagreen;
  color:white;
  font-size:16px;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-bottom:16px;
}
.validation{
 display: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-bottom: 16px;
 margin-top: 8px;
} 

.validation.val2 {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.validation p {
 float: left;
}

.validation span {
 float: right;
}

.remaining {
 clear: both;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding-top: 8px;
 margin-top: 32px;
 font-weight: bold;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <button id="first">First</button>

  <div class="applied">
      <div class="validation val">
    <p>4537 3728 3273 3284 328</p>
    <span>- £40.00</span>
    <div class="remaining">
     <p>Remaining to pay</p>
     <span class="total">£119.00</span>
     
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="validation val2">
    <p>4537 3728 3273 3284 328</p>
    <span>- £15.00</span>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the simple you just check the flag as in this snipet.

```js
$(function(){
  var flag = false;
  $('#first').click(function () {
    
    if(flag){      $('.val2').prependTo('.applied').delay(500).slideDown(400, function(){
      $('.total').html('£104.00');
      return;
    });
  }
    flag = true;
     $('.val').delay(500).slideDown(); 
  });
    });
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #5c5c5c;
}

.main {
 max-width: 375px;
  margin:16px;
}
button {
  padding:16px;
  border-radius:2px;
  border:0;
  background:seagreen;
  color:white;
  font-size:16px;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-bottom:16px;
}
.validation{
 display: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-bottom: 16px;
 margin-top: 8px;
} 

.validation.val2 {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.validation p {
 float: left;
}

.validation span {
 float: right;
}

.remaining {
 clear: both;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding-top: 8px;
 margin-top: 32px;
 font-weight: bold;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <button id="first">First</button> 
  <div class="applied">
      <div class="validation val">
    <p>4537 3728 3273 3284 328</p>
    <span>- £40.00</span>
    <div class="remaining">
     <p>Remaining to pay</p>
     <span class="total">£119.00</span>
     
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="validation val2">
    <p>4537 3728 3273 3284 328</p>
    <span>- £15.00</span>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable to track if the user has already clicked once.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmoMQG

```
var clicked = false;
$(function(){
    $('#button').click(function () {
        if (!clicked) {
            $('.val').delay(500).slideDown();
            clicked = true;
        } else {
            $('.val2').prependTo('.applied').delay(500).slideDown(400, function(){
                $('.total').html('£104.00');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The simplest solution! But will be better to make `clicked` variable is local.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your codepen (apparantly saved it as annonymous)
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWqLox

What I did was split the click functions into their own functions.

Added a count integar type variable and just added an if check in the click function that would increment the count each time. (The highest number check will set the count to -1 so when the count++ increment is hit again the variable is defaulted to 0).

```js
var firstClick = function(){
    $('.val').delay(500).slideDown(); 
};
var secondClick = function(){    $('.val2').prependTo('.applied').delay(500).slideDown(400, function(){
      $('.total').html('£104.00');
    });
};

$(function(){
  var count = 0;
  
  $('#first').click(function () {
    if(count === 0)
        {
          firstClick();
        }
    if(count === 1){
      secondClick();   
      count = -1;
    }
    
    count++;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, set a variable to track button click event.

```
var i=1;
$(function(){
 $('#first').click(function () {
    if(i==1){
      $('.val').delay(500).slideDown(); 
      i=2;
      }
    else if(i==2)  {
         $('.val2').prependTo('.applied').delay(500).slideDown(400, function(){
        $('.total').html('£104.00');
      });   
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rigtht. Try to run this snippet

```js
$(function() {

  $('#first').click(function() {
    if ($('.val').is(':visible')) {
      $('.val2').prependTo('.applied').delay(500).slideDown(400, function() {
        $('.total').html('£104.00');
      });
    } else {
      $('.val').delay(500).slideDown();
    }

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #5c5c5c;
}

.main {
  max-width: 375px;
  margin: 16px;
}

button {
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 0;
  background: seagreen;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.validation {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.validation.val2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.validation p {
  float: left;
}

.validation span {
  float: right;
}

.remaining {
  clear: both;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-top: 8px;
  margin-top: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <button id="first">Single</button>
  <div class="applied">
    <div class="validation val">
      <p>4537 3728 3273 3284 328</p>
      <span>- £40.00</span>
      <div class="remaining">
        <p>Remaining to pay</p>
        <span class="total">£119.00</span>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="validation val2">
      <p>4537 3728 3273 3284 328</p>
      <span>- £15.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```